# How to show a function is differentiable at every point in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

How do I show that a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at every point $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$?

For example,
$$f(x,y)=\ln(1+x^4+y^2)$$

Is it enough to prove that the resulting function in $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and exists for all $(x,y) $ or is there something more I have to do?

Comment: Absolute value is typical example of continuous function the has undefined derivative. One way would be with limit definition of derivative, or showing the what the derivative is and that it is defined everywhere on $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Write your function as comsition of $ln$ and a differentiable function $g(x,y)=1+x^4+y^2$  which are differentiable on $(0, \infty)$and on $R^2$ respectively. Then apply chain rule. Later is differentiable since it is polynomial in two variables.

Answer (score 2):

For the partial derivatives we have

$f_x(x,y)=\frac{4x^3}{1+x^4+y^2}$ and $f_y(x,y)=\frac{2y}{1+x^4+y^2}$.

These partial derivatives are continuous on $ \mathbb R^2$. Hence, $f$ is differentiable on $ \mathbb R^2$.